# jsmovie resizing sprite image wrongly

Tags: css, animation, sprite, jsmovie

I'm trying to use jsMovie (http://jsmovie.konsultaner.de/#/) to create sprite animation.
It works ok on the desktop browsers, however it behaves strangely on mobile devices.

I've set up a test: http://www.virtualgraphicstudio.com/test/ with slow fps ratio, so you can spot the problem on mobile devices.
It looks like the mobile browsers take the slicing dimensions wrongly and I can't find the reason why.

Here's my code:

```
        $('#battery').jsMovie({
            images : ['battery.jpg'],
            folder : 'sprites/',
            height : 394, width: 700,
            grid   : {height:394, width:700, columns:20, rows:8},
            showPreLoader : false,
            playOnLoad    : true,
            playBackwards : false,
            repeat: true,
            fps:5
        });


        $('#battery').jsMovie('addClip','battery_in',1,120);
        $('#battery').jsMovie('addClip','battery_loop',121,125);

        $('#battery').on('ended', function() {
            $('#battery').jsMovie('playClip', 'battery_loop', true, true);
        });
```

and the html

```
<div id="wrapper" style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0; width:700px; height: 394px; background-color:red">
    <div id="image"></div>
    <div id="hotspots" style="z-index: 1"></div>        
    <div id="videos" style="z-index: 2; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width:700px; height: 394px; background-color:green">
        <div id="battery"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the reason...
http://www.williammalone.com/articles/html5-javascript-ios-maximum-sprite-frames/